# Are the expire headers of Google's API library not set 1 year in the future anymore

Tags: jquery, caching, google-api

I am trying to load jQuery from google's api library, but they are all set to expire today, not 1 year in the future anymore.

I even tried https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js but that one is also set to expire today.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expires in a year for me.  You may have an interfering proxy.  From Firebug:

```
Last Modified   Tue Nov 22 2011 01:30:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Last Fetched    Tue Nov 22 2011 01:30:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Expires Tue Nov 20 2012 09:12:43 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Data Size   32103
Fetch Count 4
Device  disk
```

However, when I go to http://web-sniffer.net/ it does show today.  It might depend on which load balancer you hit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related anyhow, but I recently found that the Expires-header differs wether you use the complete version or a version shortcut in your URL:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js

```
Date    Tue, 28 Feb 2012 14:46:30 GMT
Expires Tue, 28 Feb 2012 14:46:29 GMT
```

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js

```
Date    Fri, 24 Feb 2012 19:18:25 GMT
Expires Sat, 23 Feb 2013 19:18:25 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old, I am able to shed some light on the conflicting headers:

Much like @cvk stated, you can request milestone versions as well as absolute versions of jquery. The absolute (version x.x.x) has a year expire header, because they are not going to change. However if you use a milestone version (version x.x) it will provide the latest version in that milestone, so needs a low expire header.

Use absolute versions, both for stability and the nice long expire header.